# When EarPods with microphone are attached, does iPhone use internal or external mic?

Tags: iphone, microphone, ear-phones

Is the internal or external mic used? Is there a difference in quality between the two mics?

Comment: If earphone is attached, your input audio will be the earphone mic. The difference between the both depends of the quality of your earphone...

Comment: @MrMojoRisin please submit your comment as an answer. :)

Comment: Well, it's done ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If earphone are attached, your input audio will be the earphone mic. The difference between the both depends of the quality of your earphone...